# Regex Entire Input Matches Pattern

Tags: php, regex

How can I make a regex pattern for use with the PHP [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) function that removes all characters which do not fit in a certain pattern. For example:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can negate the character set by using `^`:

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]`

The `^` only negates the existing character set `[...]` it is in, and it only applies when it is the first character inside the set. You can read more about negated character sets [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

So, finally:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $input);
```

**Edit**:
As noted in the comments below, you can also add the `+` quantifier so *consecutive* invalid characters will be replaced in 1 match of `preg_replace`'s iteration:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '', $input);
```

Comment: you could add quantifier for efficiency.